# How can I debug this code and make it correct?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I tried many times for my hamburger menu, and when I click the menu button it just doesn't open. I'm confused where I made mistakes.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#text" class="nav-link">Text</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#carouselExampleControls" class="nav-link">Slides</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#card" class="nav-link">Card</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: if you using bundle bootstrap than no need to use popper and boootstrap min same for the other  
Bundle Include every Bootstrap JavaScript plugin and dependency with one of our two bundles. Both bootstrap.bundle.js and bootstrap.bundle.min.js include Popper for our tooltips and popovers. For more information about what’s included in Bootstrap.
Separate If you decide to go with the separate scripts solution, Popper must come first (if you’re using tooltips or popovers), and then our JavaScript plugins.

Comment: Got it! I clear my code and reuse them, then it worked. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: welcome :)if its work please vote up my answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

chk this out

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">tex</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">tex</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It worked out! Thank you so much~ I found the problem comparing your code! Many many thanks!

Comment: welcome :)if its work please vote up my answer.Thanks.